# How do I configure dynamic DNS when my router does not support it?

Tags: dns, router

I have a MacBook which is connected to the net via an ancient DSL router (NAT enabled). I want to **SSH into the server** from elsewhere, but my ISP assigns new IP address every once in a while.

I would like to use a dynamic DNS service for "finding" my Mac, but the **router does not support** any dynamic DNS functionality.

What (lightweight) option is there to **update** the DNS service with current IP info **anyway**? I remember installing a clunky menu-bar app several years ago, and I would prefer something configurable from the terminal.

*NB: I feel it could be a problem when the MacBook is moved to a different network (friends, company) temporarily and attempts to connect to macbookaddress.dynamicdnz.tld suddenly hit their network. Correct?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ddclient is what I use on my Linux boxes. Works really well.

You can find instructions details here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ddclient

I think all you would need to do to get ddclient to run is to a @reboot line to your crontab and you’re set.

```
crontab -e
```

then add this line:

```
@reboot /usr/sbin/ddclient -daemon 300 -syslog
```

Comment: ddclient is available via [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) as well. Great!

Comment: In the end, I went for [no-ip.com](http://www.no-ip.com/) and their pretty OK [Mac software](http://www.no-ip.com/downloads.php?page=mac).

Answer (score 0):

You could install the [Wide-Area Bonjour preference pane](http://www.dns-sd.org/ClientSetup.html) from Apple. Not only will this cause your MacBook to register itself in DNS when you are at home behind your router, but it will do it no matter where you are.

In the prefernce pane you can enter your hostname and the [TSIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TSIG) key the server requires for authenticating dynamic DNS update requests. There is a red light/yellow light/green light widget that shows you whether the dynamic DNS request is failed/in progress/successful.

The software is quite old and has some serious problems such as complete lack of IPv6 support, but it still works with at least basic functionality. There is a link to the source code on the above page in case someone wants to modernize it, but unfortunately the link doesn't lead to the source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need another way from your router itself working out of the box and you really know what you do, you can use [DDNS-over-CWMP](https://github.com/Mamdouh-Freelancer/DDNS-Over-CWMP) it's a simple Google Script code to capture IP changes periodically or if your router powered on or rebooted by using GS as ACS endpoint for your router in CWMP settings. I wrote it for [DuckDNS.org](https://www.duckdns.org) and it works as expected. You can modify the code to work with any other DDNS provider too

[image]